# Is there a way to create a code architecture diagram, that gives an overview over R scripts that source each other?

Tags: r, architecture, structure, diagram

I have alot of different scripts in R that sources one another with `source()`. Im looking for a way to create an overview diagram, that links each script visually, so i can easily see the "source hierarchy" of my code.

The result could look something like:

[image]

I hope there is a solution, that doesnt require a software license.

Hope it makes sence! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem, your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. Please refer to this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I hope you have a good time here!

Comment: However, you may want to look at [DiagrammeR](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) or [PlantUML](https://rkrug.github.io/plantuml/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use Knime. it has the kind of diagram you are looking for. It has some scripts already wrote to clean, visualize data and write output and has integration with R and Python.

https://docs.knime.com/?category=integrations&release=2019-12
https://www.knime.com/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of example change directory to an empty directory and run the code in the Note at the end to create some sample .R files.

In the first two lines of the code below we set the `files` variable to be a character vector containing the paths to the R files of interest.  We also set `st` to the path to the main source file.  Here it is `a.R` but it can be changed appropriately.

The code first inserts the line contained in variable `insert` at the beginning of each such file.

Then it instruments `source` using the `trace` command shown so that each time `source` is run a log record is produced.   We then `source` the top level R file.

Finally we read in the log and use the igraph package to produce a tree of source files.  (Any other package that can produce suitable graphics could be used instead.)

```
# change the next two lines of code appropriately.
# Settings shown are for the files generated in the Note at the end
# assuming they are in the current directory and no other R files are.
files <- Sys.glob("*.R")
st <- "a.R"

# inserts indicated line at top of each file unless already inserted
insert <- "this.file <- normalizePath(sys.frames()[[1]]$ofile)"
for(f in files) 
  inp <- readLines(f)
  ok <- !any(grepl(insert, inp, fixed = TRUE)) # TRUE if insert not in f
  if (ok) writeLines(c(insert, input), f)
}

# instrument source and run to produce log file
if (file.exists("log")) file.remove("log")
this.file <- "root"
trace(source, quote(cat("parent:", basename(this.file), 
  "file:", file, "\n", file = "log", append = TRUE)))
source(st)  # assuming a.R is the top level program
untrace(source)

# read log and display graph
DF <- read.table("log")[c(2, 4)]

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(DF)
plot(g, layout = layout_as_tree(g))
```

For example, if we have the files generated in the Note at the end then the code above generates this diagram:

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
cat('
source("b.R")
source("c.R")
', file = "a.R")

cat("\n", file = "b.R")

cat("\n", file = "C.R")
```